# gtk_text_buffer_create_tag creates warning: 'GtkTextTag' has no property named '\u0004'

Tags: c++, c, gtk2

When I call

```
gtk_text_buffer_create_tag(buffer, "small_distance", "foreground", "green");
```

in my program it warns at runtime:
g_object_set_is_valid_property: object class 'GtkTextTag' has no property named '\u0004'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to "NULL-terminate" the list of args:

```
gtk_text_buffer_create_tag(buffer, "small_distance", 
                           "foreground", "green", 
                           NULL);
```

Notice the NULL as "last parameter".

*More on this topic:*

The param list is treated as [`g_object_set()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-set) . And it states

> value for the first property, followed optionally by more name/value pairs, **followed by NULL**